# Print out from Servlet

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, servlets

I want to print out a column from my MySQL database. I have a calendar system, where you can choose a "from" date "to" date. When you choose the time period, it should print out the COLUMN "Allday_hours" from MySQL database. I am using a javascript, AJAX and JSON. This is calling my servlet. There is connection so that works font, but I really don't know how to print the column out from my servlet. Is it some kind of `System.out.println("")` I have to use, or?

```
    package WorkPackage;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet("/getHoursSQL")
public class getHoursSQL extends HttpServlet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) 
        throws ServletException, IOException{

        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/NekiWork";
        Connection connection=null;
        String all_day_hours = null;                            // new code
        res.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");          // new code
        res.getWriter().write(all_day_hours);                   // new code

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", ""); 
            String sql = "SELECT *, (Day_hours + (Day_minutes / 100)) AS Allday_hours FROM Workdata";
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(sql);

            if(rs.next()){                                      // new code
                 all_day_hours = rs.getString("Allday_hours");  // new code
            }                                                   // new code
            pst.close();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e){

            System.out.println("Couldn't load database driver: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("SQLException caught: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        finally {

            try {
                if (connection != null) connection.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException ignored){
                System.out.println(ignored);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
<form>
        <input id="startDate" />
        <input id="endDate" />
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script>

    $(function(){
        $("#startDate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            onSelect: function(dateText,inst){
                alert(dateText);

                $.ajax({
                      url: "../getHoursSQL",
                      type: "post",
                      data: JSON,
                      success: function(data){
                          alert("success");
                          $("#result").html(data);

                      },
                      error:function(){
                          alert("failure");
                          $("#result").html('there is error while submit');
                      }  
                    });
            }
        });
    });

    $(function(){
            $("#endDate").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                onSelect: function(dateText,inst){
                    alert(dateText);

                    $.ajax({
                          url: "../getHoursSQL",
                          type: "post",
                          data: JSON,
                          success: function(data){
                              alert("success");
                              $("#result").html(data);
                          },
                          error:function(){
                              alert("failure");
                              $("#result").html('there is error while submit');
                          }  
                        });
                }
            });
        });

</script>
```

Video with error:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UzdvQ4B9clw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is replace

```
pst.executeUpdate(sql);
```

with

```
ResultSet rs = pst.execute(sql);
String all_day_hours = null;
if(rs.next()){
     all_day_hours = rs.getString("Allday_hours");
}
```

And than write this value to servlet's out stream by

```
res.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
res.getWriter().write(all_day_hours);
```

And replace

```
success: function(){
```

with

```
success: function(data){
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello again. Thanks a lot for your help. I can see all the things you say Sanjeev. I tried to put the informations in, but now I get an error from my javascript, but I will try to play around with it. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Sure .. play and have fun coding :)

Comment: Hello again. I don't know if you are still there. I have played around with it, but I still get a failure when  I run the program. I have edited my question and put a link to a youtube video with the error I get. Can you see why? Thanks a lot. Best Regards Mads.

Comment: I tried to put the:
String all_day_hours = null;
up, otherwise I got a compiler error :-/

Answer (score 0):

Use setContentType as "application/JSON" instead of text/HTML. Also if you are getting array of values from database then you have to use the GSON and convert your object to JSON object. Then use out.println and pass the converted JSON object into it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the correct code:

```
package WorkPackage;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet("/getHoursSQL")
public class getHoursSQL extends HttpServlet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) 
        throws ServletException, IOException{

        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/NekiWork";
        Connection connection=null;
                                // new code
                    // new code

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", ""); 
            String sql = "SELECT *, (Day_hours + (Day_minutes / 100)) AS Allday_hours FROM Workdata";
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(sql);
            String all_day_hours = null;    

            if(rs.next()){                                      
                 all_day_hours = rs.getString("Allday_hours");  
            }       
            res.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");          
            res.getWriter().write(all_day_hours);   
            pst.close();

        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e){

            System.out.println("Couldn't load database driver: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("SQLException caught: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        finally {

            try {
                if (connection != null) connection.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException ignored){
                System.out.println(ignored);
            }
        }
    }
}
```